# Verify compression in hadoop is successful

Tags: hadoop, compression

Hi I have used the below code to compress file present in hdfs

```
hadoop jar hadoop-streaming-2.6.0-cdh5.7.1.jar \
               -Dmapred.reduce.tasks=0 \
               -Dmapred.output.compress=true \
               -Dmapred.compress.map.output=true \
               -Dmapred.output.compression.codec=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec \
               -input ${filename} \
               -output location \
               -mapper /bin/cat \
               -inputformat org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat \
               -outputformat org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextOutputFormat
```

And again decompress it using

```
hadoop jar hadoop-streaming-2.6.0-cdh5.7.1.jar \
               -Dmapred.reduce.tasks=0 \
               -Dmapred.input.compress=true \                                            
               -Dmapred.input.compression.codec=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec \
               -input ${filename} \
               -output location \
               -mapper /bin/cat \
               -inputformat org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat \
               -outputformat org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextOutputFormat
```

But when i check for the file size it is varying by a difference of few bytes.

for example the initial file size was 43704541167 bytes 
and once i compressed and decompressed it the size was 43704541183

I would like to know if we have any way to confirm if the compression was successful without any data loss..

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Perhaps compare a hash of the two files to see if they're the same?

Comment: Hi @BinaryNerd thank you for the reply.. i tried comparing the hash of the two files but both differed. Guess this is happening because of some special characters in data..